# Interactive plot for spatial data in R markdown (to html)

Tags: r, matrix, plot

So basically I have some spatial data, which I've found weighted matrix by distance `dnearneigh` in `R` and I am wondering if I can generate an interactive plot of the link distribution by changing the distance variable for the weighted matrix.

The data set:

`CA.poly <- readShapePoly('CaliforniaCounty.shp')`

This is a shapefile for California county and using this I can generate a weight matrix based on the distance of each county.

`coords<-coordinates(CA.poly)
W_dist<-dnearneigh(coords,0,1.5,longlat = FALSE)`

And after generating the matrix I can plot the link distribution by using:

`plot(W_dist,coordinates(CA.poly))`

This will show a network of counties where two counties are connected if their distance (between centroids) are less than 1.5 km.

All the codes are in a Rmd file and I am wondering is there a way to output in html an interactive plot where you (user) can change the distance parameter (change 1.5 km to 1 km for example) and the graph will change.

I looked up methods like using shiny and plotly but I don't think they suit my goal. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to use ```manipulate``` package under R but it only works within Rstudio but I want the output to be a html file.